# How to set max execution time on individual tasks running on threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool, multitasking

I have a set of tasks in multiple levels that I need to run in parallel on threads taken from a thread pool.

I am using a countdown latch to time the overall execution of the level.

Problem: there are few tasks which get to execute more than their individual time just because of other tasks present in the same level that have more execution time. I want to avoid that.

Below is the code I'm using.

```
private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat(
            "TaskExecutor-thread-%d").build());
```

....

```
for (int i = 0; i < levels.size(); i++) {

   Set<AbstractTask> taskSet = levels.get(i);
   CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(taskSet.size());

   int maxAwaitTime = TaskExecutorHelper.getMaxAwaitTime(taskSet);  //this returns max of all 
                                                                     // execution time set for 
                                                                      //individual tasks

   for (AbstractTask t : taskSet) {
                    executor.submit(() -> { t.doExecute(input); });
   } 

   latch.await(maxAwaitTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to set a task that will interrupt execution after given timeout. The following example may give you an idea:

```
 private final ExecutorService executor = ...;
 private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = ...;

 Future future = executor.submit(() -> ... );
 ScheduledFuture scheduledFuture = scheduler.schedule(() -> future.cancel(true), 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

You will need some code to cancel timeout handler after task execution.
See [ScheduledExecutorService#schelude](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule-java.lang.Runnable-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) for details.